# Metasploit always asks me to create MSF web service account

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux, qubes-os

I run QubesOS on my laptop and created a StandaloneVM based on debian-10 template.
I installed metasploit and created a database for the MSF web service and I was given a token for the API.
I rebooted my laptop and then when I type `msfconsole` again it asks me to create a user again.

```
user@offsec:~$ msfconsole
Found a database at /home/user/.msf4/db, checking to see if it is started
Starting database at /home/user/.msf4/db... success
[?] Initial MSF web service account username? [user]:
```

What is the problem here ?